# Is $\delta_a^b \, g_{\mu\nu}$ defined?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, definition

what is $\delta_a^b \, g_{\mu\nu}$? is the multiplication of Kronecker delta function with the metric tensor when the indices are different defined?

Comment: I would say this is just some bigger tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just another tensor. From the definition of tensor product

> Given a $(l,k)$-tensor $A^{i_1\cdots i_l}_{j_1\cdots j_k}$ and a $(p,q)$-tensor $B^{i_{l+1}\cdots i_{l+p}}_{j_{k+1}\cdots j_{k+q}}$ their tensor product is a tensor $(l+p, k+q)$ defined as $$(A\otimes B)^{i_1\cdots i_li_{l+1}\cdots i_{l+k}}_{j_1\cdots j_kj_{k+1}\cdots j_{k+q}} = A^{i_1\cdots i_l}_{j_1\cdots j_k}B^{i_{l+1}\cdots i_{l+p}}_{j_{k+1}\cdots j_{k+q}}$$

So in your case call the product $T$, is a mixed tensor such that

$$T^b_{\;\;a\mu\nu} = \delta^b_{\;a} g_{\mu\nu}$$

Comment: what happens if there is a summation and a=b?, will it be 4 $g_{\mu\nu}$ or just $g_{\mu\nu}$ ?

Comment: @gumiho There'll be $4g_{\mu\nu}$ since you're tracing over the Kronecker delta